Jackson XML can't deserialize XmlElements correctly from Jakarta
I am trying to use Jackson XML for my jakarta deserialization but for xmlElements it does not seem to work and results in a null object. All other normal fields with just XmlElement do deserialize correctly. The following code is what I have for my Java class:
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "posinfo"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "PUSH")
public class PUSH {

    @XmlElement(name = "posinfo")
    protected List<PosinfoType> posinfo;

    .....
}


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "posinfoType", propOrder = {
    "delayAndINITAndARRIVAL",
    "delimiterAndAny"
})
public class PosinfoType {

    @XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(name = "DELAY", type = DELAYType.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "INIT", type = INITType.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "ARRIVAL", type = ARRIVALType.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "ONSTOP", type = ONSTOPType.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "DEPARTURE", type = DEPARTUREType.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "ONROUTE", type = ONROUTEType.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "ONPATH", type = ONPATHType.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "OFFROUTE", type = OFFROUTEType.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "END", type = ENDType.class)
    })
    protected List<Object> delayAndINITAndARRIVAL;
    @XmlElementRef(name = "delimiter", namespace = "http://example.com/tmi8/core", type = Delimiter.class, required = false)
    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    protected List<Object> delimiterAndAny;

    .....
 }

With this XML that I try to parse:
<posinfo>
    <ONROUTE>
        <timestamp>2024-05-14T16:18:14+00:00</timestamp>
        <source>VEHICLE</source>
    </ONROUTE>
    <ONSTOP>
        <timestamp>2024-05-14T16:18:14+00:00</timestamp>
        <source>VEHICLE</source>
    </ONSTOP>
    <ARRIVAL>
        <timestamp>2024-05-14T16:18:16+00:00</timestamp>
        <source>VEHICLE</source>
    </ARRIVAL>
</posinfo>

With this XML config:
object JacksonJaxbUtils {
    val objectMapperXml: ObjectMapper = XmlMapper.builder().apply {
        defaultUseWrapper(false)

        enable(ToXmlGenerator.Feature.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION)

        addModule(JakartaXmlBindAnnotationModule())

        disable(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE)
        disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
        disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
        serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
        addModule(
            JavaTimeModule().apply {
                addSerializer(XMLGregorianCalendar::class.java, XMLGregorianCalendarSerializer())
            }
        )
    }.build()

    class XMLGregorianCalendarSerializer : JsonSerializer<XMLGregorianCalendar>() {
        override fun serialize(value: XMLGregorianCalendar, generator: JsonGenerator, provider: SerializerProvider) {
            generator.writeString(value.toXMLFormat())
        }
    }
}

What am I missing/ doing wrong for it to result into a null and not a list of items?

Did you try first without the XmlAnyElement ?

@LaurentSchoelens both: delayAndINITAndARRIVAL and delimiterAndAny are null. Atleast want delayAndINITAndARRIVAL to have the list of objects (when I remove the XmlAnyElement it still gives a null for delayAndINITAndARRIVAL)
